# Как сохранять и восстанавливать настройки приложения во время сеансов?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton, qsettings

Пишу программу с графическим интерфейсом (*Python 3* + *PyQt5* + *Pyrogram*). 
Возникла необходимость создания некоторого числа кнопок, по нажатию на основную кнопку.

Идея такова - каждая новая созданная кнопка, изначально должна открывать окно авторизации с пустыми полями.

После заполнения полей и успешной авторизации за данной кнопкой должно сохраниться окно со всеми внесенными данными. 
Т.е., после того, как закрыть окно авторизации данной кнопки, а затем вновь на нее нажать, то должно открыться уже не пустое окно авторизации, а заполненное именно теми данными, которые вносились пользователем.

С последующими новыми кнопками действовать по аналогии с первой. 
Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

---

Фрагмент кода прилагаю:

```
class main_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addButton = QPushButton('Add new user')
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.test_add_but)
        self.scrollLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.scrollWidget = QWidget()
        self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout) 
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sender')
        self.show()

    def add_new_user(self):
        self.win_new_user = second_window()
        self.win_new_user.setFixedSize(700, 500)
        self.win_new_user.show()

    def test_add_but(self):
        self.button = QPushButton('New user (need authorization)')
        self.scrollLayout.addRow(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.add_new_user)


class second_window(QWidget):
    #Данный класс окна авторизации 
    # ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    myWidget = main_window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Реализовать можно все, но во всем должен быть смысл. Вы меня конечно извините, но вам надо пересмотреть свою идею. Сколько таких кнопок вы думаете может поместиться на экране? Представьте, что допустим вы сформировали (после успешной авторизации) уже СТО кнопок. Представили? А что дальше вы собираетесь с ними делать? За данной кнопкой должно сохраниться окно со всеми внесенными данными - это как? Для хранения данных вам нужна как минимум таблица, кот. надо будет сохранять на диск по завершения работы приложения. Вообще-то для хранения данных вам нужна База Данных. Подумайте над ваше сказанным.

Comment: @S. Nick, как Вы могли заметить, то в главном окне я использую `QScrollArea()`, что позволит мне создать то количество кнопок, которое мне необходимо и все они поместятся в данном окне. Что касается вашего предложения по использованию БД, так вот я использую не БД, а банально текстовый файл, в который сохраняются все необходимые данные, т.к. априори кнопок будет не очень большое количество. А фрагмент кода  приложил конкретно с главным окном, функцией добавления новой кнопки и функцией открытия окна авторизации по нажатию на созданную кнопку. Все ваши замечания уже итак учтены.

Comment: @S. Nick, данная программа была полностью реализована мной только для пяти пользователей, в ней я прописывал отдельно каждую кнопку и отдельно каждую ф-цию для каждой кнопки, но после того, как появилась необходимость добавления большего количества пользователей я задумался над тем, можно ли реализовать это созданием одной (нескольких) функций, обращаясь к которым будет создаваться кнопка, затем к которой будет привязываться, грубо говоря, свой экземпляр окна авторизации, т.к. для пяти пользователей код был уже и так достаточно большой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс [**QSettings**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) обеспечивает постоянные, независимые от платформы настройки приложения.

Единственное, что вам надо сделать перед запуском программы, это создать в текущем каталоге файл **testDb.ini**. Я в нем сохраняю данные. Внутри этого файла одна строка - **`[myDate]`**.

**testDb.ini**:

```
[myDate]
```

---

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

# testDb.ini - файл для хранения данных на диске
settings = QSettings("testDb.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)

db = {}     # Запишем данные с диска(testDb.ini) в словарь
for k in settings.allKeys():
    db[k.split("/")[-1]] = settings.value(k)

if db:   
    numMax = max([int(i) for i in list(db.keys())])
else:
    numMax = 0

class main_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        self.numButton = numMax+1                                
        self.addButton = QPushButton('Add new user', self)
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.test_add_but) 
        
        self.scrollLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.scrollWidget = QWidget()
        self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout) 
      
        if len(db):
            for v, k in sorted([ [v[0], k] for k, v in db.items()]):
                button = QPushButton(db[k][0], self)
                button.clicked.connect(lambda text, keyBtn=k: 
                               self.add_new_user(button.text(), keyBtn))
                self.scrollLayout.addRow(button)
        
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)
        
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sender')
        self.show()
        
    def add_new_user(self, text, keyBtn):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.win_new_user = second_window(self, sender, keyBtn)
        self.win_new_user.show()
   
    def test_add_but(self):
        newBtn = QPushButton('New Button{}'.format(self.numButton), self)
        button = QPushButton('New user {} (need authorization)'.format(self.numButton), self)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda text, keyBtn=str(self.numButton): 
                               self.add_new_user(button.text(), keyBtn))
        self.scrollLayout.addRow(button)
        self.numButton += 1
        
    def clickedBtnSave(self, btn, keyBtn, dataBtn):
         btn.setText(dataBtn[0].text())
         self.win_new_user.hide()
         db.setdefault(keyBtn)
         data = (dataBtn[0].text(), dataBtn[1].text(), 
                 dataBtn[2].text(), dataBtn[3].text(),)
         db[keyBtn] = data
                      
         settings.setValue("myDate/{}".format(keyBtn), data)              
         settings.sync()              
         
    def clickedBtnCancel(self):        
        self.win_new_user.hide()  

       
class second_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, btn, keyBtn):
        super(second_window, self).__init__() 
        second_window.setWindowTitle(self, 'Окно авторизации')
        self.setFixedSize(500, 400)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.groupBox = QGroupBox()
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QRect(190, 20, 421, 231))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.groupBox.setTitle('Ввод данных')
        label = QLabel(self.groupBox)
        label.setGeometry(QRect(10, 30, 391, 51))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        label.setFont(font)
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setText('Введите какие-нибудь данные.')
        
        le_first_name = QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        le_first_name.setGeometry(QRect(160, 130, 150, 20))
        le_last_name = QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        le_last_name.setGeometry(QRect(160, 160, 150, 20))
        le_telefon = QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        le_telefon.setGeometry(QRect(160, 190, 150, 20))
        le_city = QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        le_city.setGeometry(QRect(160, 220, 150, 20))
        
        if db.get(keyBtn):
            le_first_name.setText(db[keyBtn][0])
            le_last_name.setText(db[keyBtn][1])
            le_telefon.setText(db[keyBtn][2])
            le_city.setText(db[keyBtn][3])
        
        lbl_first_name = QLabel('Имя', self.groupBox)
        lbl_first_name.setGeometry(QRect(0, 130, 150, 20))
        lbl_first_name.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lbl_last_name = QLabel('Фамилия', self.groupBox)
        lbl_last_name.setGeometry(QRect(0, 160, 150, 20))
        lbl_last_name.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lbl_telefon = QLabel('Телефон', self.groupBox)
        lbl_telefon.setGeometry(QRect(0, 190, 150, 20))
        lbl_telefon.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lbl_city = QLabel('Город', self.groupBox)
        lbl_city.setGeometry(QRect(0, 220, 150, 20))
        lbl_city.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)

        dataBtn = (
            le_first_name,
            le_last_name,
            le_telefon,
            le_city,      
        )
        btn_save = QPushButton('Сохранять', self.groupBox, 
                               clicked=lambda c, btn=btn, keyBtn=keyBtn, dataBtn=dataBtn: 
                               parent.clickedBtnSave(btn, keyBtn, dataBtn )) 
        btn_save.setGeometry(QRect(140, 340, 80, 25))
        btn_cancel = QPushButton('Не сохранять', self.groupBox, 
                                  clicked=parent.clickedBtnCancel)
        btn_cancel.setGeometry(QRect(230, 340, 80, 25))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    myWidget = main_window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: огромнейшее спасибо! Это именно, то, что мне было необходимо